# SQL table self-comparison: how to eliminate duplicates

Tags: sql

I'm trying to make a self-comparison between lines of the same SQL table that have one parameter in common, and I am searching how to eliminate duplicate lines.

Here is a representation of the problem:

TABLE `item`:

```
   id   |   value
_________________
   0    |    10  
   1    |    10
```

Here is the results I want to get (either one is fine, they are equivalent):

```
  id1   |   id2        *      id1   |   id2     
___________________   O R   ___________________  
   0    |    1         *       1    |    0
```

Here is the result I get:

```
  id1   |   id2
___________________
   0    |    1
   1    |    0
```

Here is the query I have:

```
SELECT item1.id as id1, item2.id as id2
FROM item item1, item item2
WHERE item1.value = item2.value
      AND item1.id <> item2.id
```

Is there a way to tell it that if the pair of ids "(0,1)" is a result, then it's should not return the inversed pair "(1,0)" ?

Thank you for taking the time to read, and don't hesitate to tell me if I'm unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just take an arbitrary decision that you always list pairs as `(low,high)`, and use `<` instead of `<>`:

```
SELECT item1.id as id1, item2.id as id2
FROM   item item1, item item2
WHERE  item1.value = item2.value
AND    item1.id < item2.id
```

Comment: Well... why didn't I think of that now ? I feel silly. Thanks a lot :)